# Metapost : Can I have a path which is partially unconnected

Tags: metapost

Hello Metapost user ,

Can I have a path which is partially unconnected in the middle.
The code I am expecting :

```
path p ; 
pair A, B, C, D, E, F ,G ; 
A=( 0,  0) ;
B=(10,  0) ;
C=(10,-10) ;
D=(20,-10) ;
E=(30,-10) ;
F=(30,  0) ;
G=(40,  0) ;
p = A -- B -- C  no-connection   D -- E -- F -- G ;  

output : 

   A     B              F       G
   o-----o              o-------o
         |              |
         o        o-----o 
         C        D     E
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a `path` in Metapost is a continuous linked sequence of one or more points.  But you can use `subpath` to pick out certain parts of it.  So you could get your desired output like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path p ; 
pair A, B, C, D, E, F ,G ; 
A=( 0,  0) ;
B=(10,  0) ;
C=(10,-10) ;
D=(20,-10) ;
E=(30,-10) ;
F=(30,  0) ;
G=(40,  0) ;

p = A -- B -- C --  D -- E -- F -- G ; 

draw subpath (0, 2) of p;
draw subpath (3, 6) of p;

defaultscale := 0.5;
dotlabeldiam := 2;
forsuffixes @ = A, B, F, G:
    dotlabel.top(str @, @);
endfor

forsuffixes @ = C, D, E:
    dotlabel.bot(str @, @);
endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you all the times.  Your post makes me keep going.